Java Spring AWS S3 image upload error (The authorization header is malformed)
I'm having a problem uploading an image to AWS S3 through Spring server.
The error is: The authorization header is malformed; the authorization component "Credential== {access-key}/{YYYYMMDD}/{region}/s3/aws4_request" is malformed. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AuthorizationHeaderMalformed; Request ID: {Request ID}; S3 Extended Request ID: {Extended Request ID}; Proxy: null)
and my code
gradle
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:3.0.3'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.12.638'

S3Config
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class S3Config {
    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
    private String accessKey;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.region.static}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3(){
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

        return AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
    }
}

ImageUploadService (The import statement was omitted considering the length)
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class ImageUploadService {
    private final AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    @Value("${cloud.aws.s3.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;

    public String upload(MultipartFile image){
        if(Objects.isNull(image) || image.isEmpty() || Objects.isNull(image.getOriginalFilename())){
            throw new S3ImageException(ErrorCode.IMAGE_NOT_EXISTS);
        }
        return this.uploadImage(image);
    }

    private String uploadImage(MultipartFile image){
        this.validateImageFileExtension(Objects.requireNonNull(image.getOriginalFilename()));
        try{
            return this.uploadImageToS3(image);
        }catch (IOException e){
            throw new S3ImageException(ErrorCode.IO_EXCEPTION_ON_IMAGE_UPLOAD);
        }
    }

    private void validateImageFileExtension(String fileName){
        int lastDotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (lastDotIndex == -1) {
            throw new S3ImageException(ErrorCode.EXTENSION_NOT_EXISTS);
        }

        String extension = fileName.substring(lastDotIndex + 1).toLowerCase();
        List<String> allowedExtensionList = List.of("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");

        if (!allowedExtensionList.contains(extension)) {
            throw new S3ImageException(ErrorCode.INVALID_IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION);
        }
    }

    private String uploadImageToS3(MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        String originalFileName = image.getOriginalFilename();
        String extension = Objects.requireNonNull(originalFileName).substring(originalFileName.lastIndexOf("."));

        String s3FileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 10) + originalFileName;

        InputStream is = image.getInputStream();
        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

        ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        metadata.setContentType("image/" + extension);
        metadata.setContentLength(bytes.length);
        ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

        // point of error
        try{
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3FileName, byteArrayInputStream, metadata)
                    .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest); // <- point of error
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            throw new S3ImageException(ErrorCode.PUT_IMAGE_EXCEPTION);
        }finally{
            byteArrayInputStream.close();
            is.close();
        }

        return amazonS3.getUrl(bucketName, s3FileName).toString();
    }

    public void deleteImageFromS3(String imageAddress){
        String key = getKeyFromImageAddress(imageAddress);
        try{
            amazonS3.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
        }catch (Exception e) {
            throw new S3ImageException(ErrorCode.IO_EXCEPTION_ON_IMAGE_DELETE);
        }
    }

    private String getKeyFromImageAddress(String imageAddress){
        try{
            URL url = new URL(imageAddress);
            String decodingKey = URLDecoder.decode(url.getPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            return decodingKey.substring(1);
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            throw new S3ImageException(ErrorCode.IO_EXCEPTION_ON_IMAGE_DELETE);
        }
    }
}

ImageUploadCOntroller
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "${requestMapping.imageUpload}", produces="application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public class ImageUploadController {
    final ImageUploadService imageUploadService;

    @PostMapping("${imageUpload.testUrl}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadImage(@RequestPart(value = "image", required = false)MultipartFile image){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(imageUploadService.upload(image));
    }
}

What I did:
1. I tried changing the upload method of ImageUploadService. But it doesn't work
public String upload(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException{
        String fileName = UUID.randomUUID() + "-" + multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();

        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
        objectMetadata.setContentLength(multipartFile.getInputStream().available());

        amazonS3.putObject(bucketName, fileName, multipartFile.getInputStream(), objectMetadata);

        return amazonS3.getUrl(bucketName, fileName).toString();
    }

2. I checked whether accessKey, secretKey, region, and bucketName are correct. But it doesn't work
3. I deleted the S3 bucket and AWS IAM account, created it again, and ran the original code. But it doesn't work

I tried to find the problem in the Config class or Service class, but the answer was in properties. Another = was added between the above sentences like this cloud.aws.credentials.access-key = ABCDEFG -> cloud.aws.credentials.access-key= = ABCDEFG. I only modified the part corresponding to the accessKey string and did not properly check the part before it. I'll save the question for anyone who repeats my stupid mistake. I don't know if there are people who make the same mistake as me.

If you ended up here while looking for a solution to the problem 'The authorization header is malformed', the solution is as follows.

Check whether the Access Key and Secret Key are interchanged.
Check for typos in the key string
Check for typos in the properties sentence

To avoid being like me, read every single word of the properly.
